# How to preserve default syntax highlighting colors in JavaScript console

Tags: javascript, typescript, logging, console.log, winston

As shown near the green arrows, the default `console.log` colorizes values based on whether they are `string` or `number`.

[image: replit]

As shown near the red arrows, my attempt at using Winston to format logs a certain way unfortunately abandons the colorizing of those values.

[Replit demo](https://replit.com/@RyanWalsh14/Winston-logging-in-TypeScript#index.ts)

```
function getArgumentsPreserved(providedArguments: Arguments): string {
  // https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/how-to-use-util-inspect/
  // https://github.com/chalk/chalk/issues/118#issuecomment-1221385194
  return util.inspect(providedArguments, { colors: false, depth: null });
}

const simpleConsoleLogging = winston.format.combine(
  // Simple console logging for local environment.
  winston.format.timestamp(),
  winston.format.printf((info) => {
    const { level, message, timestamp, ...rest } = info;
    const coloredTimestampAndLevel = colorizer.colorize(level, `${timestamp} ${level}:`);

    //const syntaxHighlightedObjects = Object.keys(rest).length > 0 ? getArgumentsPreserved(rest) : '';
    const syntaxHighlightedObjects = Object.keys(rest).length > 0 ? JSON.stringify(rest) : ''; // TODO: How can we reenable the syntax coloring that console.log had by default?
    return `${coloredTimestampAndLevel} ${message} ${syntaxHighlightedObjects}`; // https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/issues/1388#issuecomment-432932959
  }),
);
```

I've experimented with `util.inspect` but haven't gotten it to work.

### UPDATE

Now see the [new version here](https://replit.com/@RyanWalsh14/Winston-logging-in-TypeScript-v2#index.ts).

It's very close to working!

But as you can see in the screenshot, keys like 'abc' and 'def' are missing.

[image: updated screenshot]

```
function getArgumentsPreserved(providedArguments: Arguments): string {
  if (Object.keys(providedArguments).length > 0) {
    const copiedArr = getRealKeys(providedArguments);
    // https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/how-to-use-util-inspect/
    // https://github.com/chalk/chalk/issues/118#issuecomment-1221385194
    return util.inspect(copiedArr, { colors: true, depth: null });
  } else {
    return '';
  }
}

function getRealKeys(rest: Arguments) {
  const result: string[] = [];
  Object.keys(rest).forEach(key => {
    result.push(rest[key])
  })
  return result;
}

const simpleConsoleLogging = winston.format.combine(
  // Simple console logging for local environment.
  winston.format.timestamp(),
  winston.format.printf((info) => {
    const { level, message, timestamp, ...rest } = info;
    const coloredTimestampAndLevel = colorizer.colorize(level, `${timestamp} ${level}:`);

    //const syntaxHighlightedObjects = Object.keys(rest).length > 0 ? util.inspect(copiedArr, undefined, undefined, true) : ''; // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74186705/how-to-preserve-default-syntax-highlighting-colors-in-javascript-console
    const syntaxHighlightedObjects = getArgumentsPreserved(rest); // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74186705/how-to-preserve-default-syntax-highlighting-colors-in-javascript-console

    return `${coloredTimestampAndLevel} ${message} ${syntaxHighlightedObjects}`; // https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/issues/1388#issuecomment-432932959
  }),
);
```

Comment: You would have to detect the argument type and colorize yourself. I guess that's how native `console.log` does that.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski I updated the question.  I'm using https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/how-to-use-util-inspect/ Do you know how I should fix getRealKeys()? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`console.log` in Node.js actually uses the `inspect` function from the built-in `util` module, so you could just use that as well:

```
const syntaxHighlightedObjects = util.inspect(rest, undefined, undefined, true);
```

The last argument is if we want color or not (spoiler alert: we do). The second and third are "show hidden properties" and "depth to display", respectively.

---

If you only want to display the "real" keys, you can do that like this:

```
function getArgumentsPreserved(providedArguments: Arguments): string {
  if (Object.keys(providedArguments).length > 0) {
    const copied = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(providedArguments));
    
    return util.inspect(copied, { colors: true, depth: null, showHidden: false });
  } else {
    return '';
  }
}
```

This works because `Object.entries` only gets the object's own enumerable keys, which is what you were originally after. Then we can use `Object.fromEntries` to quickly get back an object.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help so far. As you can see in my updated question, I think we're very close. Do you have any idea why certain keys are missing?

Comment: @Ryan I commented on your REPL instead.

Comment: @Ryan I see now, I updated the answer and forked your REPL (will comment with a link on repl.it).

Comment: This isn't quite right yet because it doesn't handle arrays the same as `console.log`. (See the test case `logger.success("demo", ["hooray", "yay!"]);`) But I'll accept your answer anyway because I can figure it out from here. Thanks!

Comment: I think https://replit.com/@RyanWalsh14/Winston-logging-in-TypeScript-v3#index.ts is correct and that this is what I was missing: `function isArray(x): boolean {
  const splat = x[Symbol.for('splat')];
  return Array.isArray(splat[0]);
}`